# Count total combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have K distinct characters. Using these characters you can make various strings of length 1 to  N and characters can be repeated in these strings. Now you have to count total combinations of three strings from all the strings such that they have no common prefix (proper/non proper). example if K=2 and N=2 answer is 6. I came to an approach which results in the following summation.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=j}^n \sum_{j=i}^n K^j(K^i-1)(K^k-K^{k-i}-K^{k-j})$$

Please justify if this is right or else suggest any good approach for this.

Comment: "justify if this is right" Wouldn't it be more logical if you provide your own derivation?

Comment: Since i have to pick three strings so i fixed length of the three strings as L1,L2,L3 such that L1<=L2<=L3 and then for length L1 i have K^L1 options and for L2 with no common prefix i have K^L2 - K^(L2-L1) and for L3 length i have K^L3-K^(L3-L2)-K^(L3-L1) options so i product them all for all possible L1,L2,L3 with a summation. But since i have to make a program for it where N varies from 1 to 10^9 and K from 1 to 26 so i cant use nested loops, so is there any better option. Also check whether this approach is right or not.

Comment: The ordering of indexes in your summation look funny. In your approach, the formula (I think) should be $ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i}^N \sum_{k=j}^N K^i (K^j-K^i)(K^k-K^{k-j}-K^{k-i})$. Anyway, the approach seems wrong to me because it counts twice the combinations with equal sized strings (say, {A BB BA} {A BA BB} are counted as distinct)

Comment: It's probably just unfamiliarity with the subject, but I don't understand what's being counted here. In the $K=N=2$ example, I see there are $6$ strings under consideration, namely A, B, AA, AB, BA, and BB, but I don't see what combinations of three strings to count that also total $6$.

Comment: {AB,BA,BB},{AA,BA,BB},{AA,AB,BA},{AA,AB,BB},{A,BA,BB},{B,AA,AB}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me use $M$ instead of your $K$. Then your formula, after polishing up the indexes and correcting for repeated counts, gives

$$C_{N,M}=\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i}^N \sum_{k=j}^N \frac{M^i (M^j-M^{j-i})(M^k-M^{k-j}-M^{k-i})}{a_{i,j,k}!}$$

where $a_{i,j,k}\in \{ 1,2,3\}$ is the number of equal elements in $\{i,j,k\}$

Some values: $C_{2,2}=6$, $C_{2,3}=139$, $C_{3,2}=166$, $C_{3,3}=7060$

Update: it looks difficult to evaluate it exactly for large $N$. Perhaps some asymptotics can be obtained by probabilistic arguments, but I couldn't get anything useful. A straightforward replacement of the sum by an integral (assuming $a_{i,j,k}=1$) gives a leading term of the form

$$C_{N,M}\approx \frac{M^{3N}}{6 \log^3(M)}$$

This seems numerically fair.

Comment: Hey can you tell me an approach so that i can write a program for it where N would range from 1 to 10^9 and M <= 26

Comment: N =10^9 looks rather formidable to compute exactly, you couldn't even store the number :-) I added some asymptotic approximation.

Comment: Actually i need to take modulo with 10^9+7 of the hole quantity